# How can I pass a closure with generics to a function without making that function generic?

Tags: generics, rust, closures

I have a function that works with a enum to apply binary functions. This is for an interpreter:

```
use std::ops::*;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub enum Scalar {
    I64(i64),
    I32(i32),
    //many many others
}

pub trait TMath: Add + Mul + Sized {} //mark numerical types
impl<T: Add + Mul> TMath for T {}

fn add<T: TMath>(x: T, y: T) -> <T as Add>::Output {
    x + y
}

pub type NatBinExpr<T: TMath> = Fn(&T, &T) -> T;
```

I want to do:

```
let result = bin_op(add, &Scalar::I32(1), &Scalar::I32(2));
```

but also to make it work for arbitrary binary functions:

```
let result = bin_op(Scalar::concat, &Scalar::I32(1), &Scalar::I32(2));
```

However, I haven't found a way to pass the closure without making `bin_op` generic:

```
fn bin_op(apply: &NatBinExpr???, x: &Scalar, y: &Scalar) -> Scalar {
    match (x, y) {
        (Scalar::I64(a), Scalar::I64(b)) => Scalar::I64(apply(a, b)),
        (Scalar::I32(a), Scalar::I32(b)) => Scalar::I32(apply(a, b)),
    }
}
```

Making `bin_op` generic is not right; `bin_op` operates on `Scalar`, but the internal operation is generic.

I originally [asked this question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/9j8o8e/how_pass_a_closure_with_generics_to_a_non_generic/)

Comment: It looks like you would need higher kinded types to express this, which currently aren't supported by rust.

Answer (score 1):

There are essentially two distinct ways to talk about function types:

- pointers: `fn(A, B) -> C`,
- traits: `Fn(A, B) -> C`, `FnMut(A, B) -> C`, `FnOnce(A, B) -> C`.

In either case, they are characterized by the arguments and result types.

So, what are the arguments and result types of `apply`?

**It depends.**

From your example, we can see that it is `FnOnce(T, T) -> T` for `T` in `[i64, i32, ...]`.

This is not *one* type, this is *many* types. Therefore it needs not a single function but many functions; or perhaps a function object implementing `FnOnce` multiple times.

---

The function object route is only available on nightly, and requires an awful lot of boilerplate (for which macros would help):

```
#![feature(fn_traits)]
#![feature(unboxed_closures)]

use std::ops::*;

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq, PartialOrd)]
pub enum Scalar {
    I64(i64),
    I32(i32),
    //many many others
}

pub trait TMath: Add + Mul + Sized {} //mark numerical types

impl<T: Add + Mul> TMath for T {}

struct Adder;

impl FnOnce<(i64, i64)> for Adder {
    type Output = i64;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (i64, i64)) -> i64 {
        args.0 + args.1
    }
}

impl FnMut<(i64, i64)> for Adder {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (i64, i64)) -> i64 {
        args.0 + args.1
    }
}

impl Fn<(i64, i64)> for Adder {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: (i64, i64)) -> i64 {
        args.0 + args.1
    }
}

impl FnOnce<(i32, i32)> for Adder {
    type Output = i32;
    extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: (i32, i32)) -> i32 {
        args.0 + args.1
    }
}

impl FnMut<(i32, i32)> for Adder {
    extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: (i32, i32)) -> i32 {
        args.0 + args.1
    }
}

impl Fn<(i32, i32)> for Adder {
    extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: (i32, i32)) -> i32  {
        args.0 + args.1
    }
}

fn bin_op<F>(apply: &F, x: Scalar, y: Scalar) -> Scalar
    where
        F: Fn(i64, i64) -> i64,
        F: Fn(i32, i32) -> i32,
{
    match (x, y) {
        (Scalar::I64(a), Scalar::I64(b))
            => Scalar::I64((apply as &Fn(i64, i64) -> i64)(a, b)),
        (Scalar::I32(a), Scalar::I32(b))
            => Scalar::I32((apply as &Fn(i32, i32) -> i32)(a, b)),
        _ => unreachable!(),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let result = bin_op(&Adder, Scalar::I32(1), Scalar::I32(2));
    println!("{:?}", result);
}
```

[Prints `I32(3)`.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=44b2f7d4b89bf093bda333023c29fcce&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: This is as verbose or more than the normal way? If it can't collapse to just pass (A, B) -> C without implement per operator then I don't see the point.

Comment: @mamcx: It's definitely on the verbose side of things, and essentially boils down to Rust not supporting overloading. Honestly, at this point I would go with a custom `trait BinOp { fn on_i64(&self, i64, i64) -> i64; fn on_i32(&self, i32, i32) -> i32; ... }` (with a method for each type) and then implement it for `Adder`, `Muler`, etc...

Comment: @mamcx You could probably create a `macro_rules!` macro to minimize repetition.